# React native SQLite Windows : compile time error

Tags: react-native, react-native-windows

I am trying to connect the SQLite from react-native windows. it's thrown the error in SQLite "open"  method.

So, I am open the react-native windows SQLite Solutions. it's mapped old react-native libraries. so, I updated the references and build the solution. it's compiled without error. and add the package in

> PackageProviders.Add(SQLite.ReactPackageProvider());

but the plugin code is not reflected in react-native.

so, I moved the code to the main project. it's thrown the compile-time error

[image]

Please guide me any know upgrade the react-native SQLite storage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please open your DB and check whether the column actually exists, and also try to change DATABASE_VERSION to 2. Please let us know the result

Comment: it's not a db. react-native bridge, method open throw the SQLite module not available in react native 0.63 @KenLee